# Append data with Poi without overwriting headers

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I've the code below, where I want to append the data in a .xlsx file, but the new inputs just over write the header rows that I already have in the existing file. I know there is an issue with the XSSFRow, as I don't know how to define where I want the new input to be written in.

Can someone please direct me or help me identify how to fix the issue? It would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Nikos.

```
public static String path = "File Path";
public static String excelFile = "workbook.xlsx";
public static XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook;
public static XSSFSheet mySheet;
public static XSSFRow myRow;

public static void appendValues() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Appending values");
    File testFile = new File(path + excelFile);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(testFile);
    // Finds the workbook instance for XLSX file
    myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    // Return first sheet from the XLSX workbook
    mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

    myRow = mySheet.createRow(mySheet.getLastRowNum());
    System.out.println("Row: " + (myRow));



    Map<String,String> appendData=new HashMap<>();

    appendData.put("Defect Reference", "Defect ref");
    appendData.put("Defect ID", "ID");
    appendData.put("Fielda", "field");

    String[] headerArray = getHeaders().toArray(new String[0]);


    for(int i=0;i<headerArray.length;i++) {
        String val=appendData.get(headerArray[i]);
        if(val!=null)
        {
            Cell cell = myRow.createCell(i);
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell.setCellValue(val);
            System.out.println("insert Value: " + val);
        }
        else
        {
            Cell cell = myRow.createCell(i);
            cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
            cell.setCellValue("");
        }

    }

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + excelFile);
    myWorkBook.write(fos);
    fos.close();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `mySheet.getLastRowNum()` returns the index of the last row of the sheet. Which in your case of reading from an existing Excel file with only the headers is the header row itself.

Thus the next call to `mySheet.createRow(mySheet.getLastRowNum())` do exactly what you described: create a NEW row at the position of the header row, overwriting it with new data.

You already know how to use sheet.createRow(); so simply start creating row from index 1 onward and writing data to it. Row number 0 is the header row.

Comment: Even when I myRow = mySheet.createRow(mySheet.getLastRowNum() + 1); it still overwrites it. @Hung, any suggestions on how to implement that in my code?

Comment: That shouldn't be possible if your header row is indeed the first row. Try printing out the getLastRowNum()?

Comment: I did     int appendRow = mySheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; &  myRow = mySheet.createRow(appendRow);

Comment: Sorry, I don't seem to be able to delete the above comment, wasn't finished and accidentally pressed the "Add Comment" button. Yeah, I don't understand it either, appendRow = mySheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; & myRow = mySheet.createRow(appendRow);.  I sys.Printed both values and they are above 0 and yet it's writing in row A.

Comment: Strange. I copied and pasted your code above and it works as expected with getLastRowNum() + 1. Are you testing with the above code or your working code? And make sure your POI is the latest version?

Comment: I'm testing the above code using apache poi 3.14 :/ I must be doing something wrong somewhere but I can't understand what it is. It either doesn't write anythign or over writes the header row.

Comment: Try running the above code twice. Does it append 2 new rows into your Excel file or there's only 1 data row on the first row?

Comment: Tried that, only one row on the first line

Comment: I'm stumped. I tried running your exact code with **myRow = mySheet.createRow(mySheet.getLastRowNum() + 1);** and it works. Wrote my own getHeaders(), but I doubt yours is any different than mine. Either 1) try it on a new file or 2) try mySheet.createRow(1)?

Comment: Hey @Hung, I'm as much perplexed as you are. I created a new class and for some apparent reason it worked on the second class. This is some strange stuff. Regardless I'm very helpful of your help and time. Much appreciated mate.

Comment: i'd also appreciate a +1 on my question, I want to go over 50points so I can comment on forums :D